# How can i put JSON response in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON response. The json post is: SubmitPerformedDeed. And i get this back:

```
{"error":false,"shareurl":"http://groenedaad-dev.lostboys.nl/?isnew=1&pid=155#pid=155","title":"Eigenhandig m’n kantoor een stukje duurzamer gemaakt. Check m’n Groene Daad voor vandaag!","pid":155,"firstname":"sdf","deedpoints":2,"deednumber":20,"deedtitle":"deed 20","company":"asdfsdf","office":"ass","alias":"sdfsxx","thumbnail":"/Uploads/Deeds/155/thumbnail.jpg"}
```

But how can i put that Json value's response in jquery. How can i put that in a array or ?

Comment: Can you show some of your code, specifically the part(s) where the request is made?

Comment: How are you retrieving the JSON string? Via a `jQuery.get()`?

Comment: When you say 'put that Json value's response in jquery' do you mean turn your response string into a javascript object? If so, look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get what he's asking?

Comment: Maybe?  I understand fully what he is asking.  He has generated a server response and probably doesnt know how to get jquery to send the request that will retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var parsedData = $.parseJSON(str);

$.each(parsedData, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value); 
});
```

---

You should actually be able to just use `.each()` for this, as it's a "generic iterator function":

```
$.each(str, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is [javascript](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) out there that will take a JSON response and put it back in to a javascript object:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in your success callback

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$.each({your returned json},funciton(key,value){

});
```

here each function can iterate over each json element. so in loop's first iteration key represent "error" and value represent the "false"  and so on. now you can store/use this method in accordance with your need.